# Translation help please

Tags: translation

I believe I have a carved stamp but do not know the translation..And information would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Stamp base]
[image: side]
[image: top]

Comment: Please add more photos of it，other part appeared below your hand in the first image。

Comment: the first picture was taken in a mirror, since the seal was reversed...Will get other pictures posted...any idea what it was from or used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the stamp says 乾隆年制

乾隆 (Qianlong) is an Emperor from Qing Dynasty [Qianlong Emperor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qianlong_Emperor)

年(Nian):year, time

制(Zhi):made

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that would mean "made during the time of Emperor Qianlong"?

Comment: @Jas17931 You're correct.

Comment: Yes, it means that.

If it is a real antique, it is valuable :)

Comment: Wow, I had no idea.  Was in a box I bought at an estate sale.  Looks like it is missing a piece.  There is a brass type washer on one end with wood particles in the center.  What would this have been used for?  Any idea what the composition is or how I can validate age?

Comment: Looks like a snuff tobacco bottle. Google it and I am sure you can get lots of information. BTW, please accept my answer if it has answered your original question :)

Comment: I think its a reproduction, looks too good for 300+ years...plus not sure how advanced adhesives were to attach the brass to the carving. 

 Didn't glow under black light but hot needle does penetrate, however not easily and not deep.